# Different settings after update? Can't change language version

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to change the language version in Visual Studio 15.8.2. I've done this before, but after recently updating, the settings seem to have changed. I've tried going to project properties, but the only menu options are Common Properties and Configuration Properties. I've also looked in the Configuration Manager under the Build menu, but no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you exactly want to change? Visual Studio IDE language? But you are talking about the project, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I guess it's worth noting that I was able to ind the settings when creating a new project, but the one that I created through Unity doesn't have the same settings. I need to change the language version, but that option doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @Esko I'm trying to change the C# language version.It's not where it normally is in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the C# Language version from project properties under Build / Advanced:

[image]

Comment: it's not there. I'm trying to upload a screen capture now

Comment: You are viewing the properties of the ***solution*** not the project. Right click on the ***project*** and select properties.

Comment: I selected the project. It's still showing me the same thing.

Comment: If you still see Common properties and Configuration properties, you are still in solution-properties... Project-properties look totally different and should open as a new tab in the IDE editor.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. When I try to select the project, it only selects the solution. I can't actually see the project in the explorer, so I tried using it from the dropdown menu and that still isn't working.

Comment: Is this asp.net? Are you sure this is not a web site -project? If it is, it does not have project-properties, I recommend converting to ***web application*** -project. Or maybe you opened it wrong with "open web site" and not "open project"

Comment: Reopen the project with "Open project/solution", not "Open web site"

Comment: I created a new script in Unity and opened it with VS. I've tried opening it the way you suggested and there's no change. There's still a .csproj file and .sln file so I have no idea why the project itself isn't showing in the explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the C# language version for each project under Properties > Build > Advanced > Language version

Comment: what I'm saying is that the setting isn't there.

Comment: I tested this with a 15.8.2 installation. So the latest update can't be the only reason why it isn't there for you.

Comment: It seems that the project itself isn't showing in the explorer, so I've been selecting the solution. I guess the question now is how I can actually select the project without it showing. I tried using the dropdown menu, but the screen flashes and the properties window doesn't open.

Comment: I suggest you ask another question with your new problem.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should. Sorry, I'm new to this so it's frustrating to be experiencing a problem that stops me from progressing after I've barely even started

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I was selecting the project file but, for some reason, it doesn't allow you to access Unity properties by default. In case anyone else has this issue:

Tools -> Options -> Tools for Unity -> General, change access to project properties to true, and restart.

Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score -1):

try to go under Tools->Options->Enviroment->Internationals Settings.
Also there's a textbox named Search Options up to option tabs.
There are's options under Project tab, Debug and Tools.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the language, just the language version (e.g. C# 5 to C# 7.1).